# Why function in the screen is still running after navigator pop a screen?

Tags: flutter

How can I completely dispose the function/screen?

Below the reproduce code, after I press navigator pop to the home screen, I expected the next screen is popped and all function is stopped, but the function in the while keeps running.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class Config {
  static int count = 0;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class NextScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NextScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<NextScreen> createState() => _NextScreenState();
}

class _NextScreenState extends State<NextScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  int timerCount = 0;
  bool status = false;
  bool isCurrentStatus = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getInit();
  }

  void getInit() {
    try {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        startLoopStatus();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('[getInit] ERROR:: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> startLoopStatus() async {
    print('[startLoopStatus] Running startLoopStatus 001.');
    print(isCurrentStatus);
    while (status == false && isCurrentStatus) {
      if (mounted) {
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
          setState(() {
            timerCount += 1;
          });
        });
      }

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        debugPrint("delay----------");
        Config.count += 1;
        print(Config.count);
      });
      await loopArrive();
    }
  }

  Future<void> loopArrive() async {
    print('[loopArrive] Running loopArrive 001.');
    print('[loopArrive] timerCount: $timerCount');
    try {
      if (mounted) {
        if (ModalRoute.of(context)!.isCurrent) {
          print('[loopArrive] Running loopArrive 002.');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('[loopArrive] ERROR:: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('[NextScreen] dispose()');
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Next'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: const SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Please see the terminal output.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const NextScreen()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Go to next page'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no condition in your code to stop the execution. You could break the loop if `!mounted` is true, and execution would stop.

Comment: but I have the poped the screen, is it a Flutter mechanism which even the screen is poped but everything are kept?

Answer (score 1):

Just put a variable to stop the loop here :

```
onPressed: () {
              stopTheLoop = true;
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const NextScreen()),
            );}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i want know is any solution for totally dispose/clean the screen in case i forget to clean the function / timer / listen.

Answer (score 0):

The second screen's state continues to exist even when you navigate to the home screen. If your method that displays messages is running periodically using something like a Timer or Future.delayed, it will continue running until explicitly stopped.

To ensure that the method stops when you navigate away from the second screen, you can use the dispose method of the StatefulWidget.

So you can add a Timer to cancel with the dispose call.
But also with that the :

```
while (status == false && isCurrentStatus) {}
```

will continue to work !! so you can add a `Completer<void>` to finish the block..

the full code :

```
int timerCount = 0;
  bool status = false;
  bool isCurrentStatus = true;
  late Timer _timer;
  bool isActive = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getInit();
  }

  void getInit() {
    try {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        startLoopStatus();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('[getInit] ERROR:: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> startLoopStatus() async {
    print('[startLoopStatus] Running startLoopStatus 001.');
    print(isCurrentStatus);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) async {
    while (status == false && isCurrentStatus && isActive) {
      if (mounted) {
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
          setState(() {
            timerCount += 1;
          });
        });
      }

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        debugPrint("delay----------");
        Config.count += 1;
        print(Config.count);
      });
      await loopArrive();
    }
   });
  }

  Future<void> loopArrive() async {
    print('[loopArrive] Running loopArrive 001.');
    print('[loopArrive] timerCount: $timerCount');
    try {
      if (mounted) {
        if (ModalRoute.of(context)!.isCurrent) {
          print('[loopArrive] Running loopArrive 002.');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('[loopArrive] ERROR:: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('[NextScreen] dispose()');
     isActive = false;
     _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i want know is any solution for totally dispose/clean the screen in case i forget to clean the function / timer / listen.